# Source code generation in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, code-generation

I have a project where a large amount of C++ code is auto generated from some meta descriptions into multiple files. How do I make Xcode 4 automatically add these files into the project whenever happens the new build?

**NOTE:** I'm aware of build phases and custom scripts but all I could find was resources related: copy resource files to the final application bundle. In my case I need to make Xcode 4 automatically inject these autogenerated files into the application build process...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding a "Run Script" build phase.  This will allow you to run an arbitrary shell script, which you can use to do whatever extra steps you need to do.

Select your target in Xcode4, click "Add Build Phase" and then select "Add Run Script"

Comment: As wrote in the original post I'm not sure how it's going to work. I have some meta files and I already have a shell script which generates C++ files. By simply adding this script to the "Run Script" build phase all my C++ generated files will be compiled automatically?

Comment: No, not unless the script also compiles them.  You could add the generated files to the compile sources build step though, assuming you know their names.  If you don't, then you might want to do the compilation in a script as well.

Comment: I don't know the file names beforehand. Could you please show/point to an example of such a script that does compilation itself?

Comment: I don't have one to hand, nor have I seen one used inside the xcode environment, but we're just talking old school shell scripts and make files basically, using g++ manually like we did before we had IDEs.  Maybe take a look at http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html

Comment: I'm aware of Make and actually a big fan of it. The problem is it's not possible to build and run on the device using Make files. So I had to stick to the Xcode but with all its bells and whistles it doesn't allow me to accomplish some advanced techniques.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure why you can't kick off a Make run through a shell script just to build the generated code.  That was about all I have in terms of ideas.  I hope you figure out how to get your build working!  Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3300/discussion-between-micah-hainline-and-pachanga)